# How is the page title tag determined

Tags: discussion, support, title

Currently looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720429/how-do-i-set-the-window-screen-size-in-xna) question on Stack Overflow.

I notice that the title of the web page is "fullscreen - How do I..."  For the first time, I noticed that S.O. places one of the question's tags in the page title.  However, I'm not sure how this is chosen.  It's not strictly alphabetical, nor is it the left-most tag in the question, nor is it the tag with the most followers.

So, my first question is, how is tag displayed in the page title determined?

My second question is, do you agree that in the example question, the title tag should be xna, since that has more followers, is listed first, and is generally more relevant to the question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usually the tag included in the title is picked exactly like you expect - it's the top tag on the question. However, we try not to duplicate information more than absolutely necessary, so we don't bother prepending the tag name when it's already used in the title elsewhere.

In this case, the word "xna" is already in the title of the question, so we move on to the next most prominent tag. This question only has one more tag, so it's the one we use. If there were no other tags, the question title would be tag-less altogether.

Comment: Smart.  Is prominence determined by number of followers, or by order of chosen tags?

Comment: @NickVaccaro If I recall right, the order of the tags is determined by the number of questions in the tag and the tags for the title are picked in the same order. I don't believe we take the number of followers into account at all.

Comment: Right, that makes much more sense.  I did a mouse-over and saw number of followers first, so that was the first thing that came to mind.  Thanks for your prompt answer.